# argparse to accept random arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python application that implements `argparse` with a set of arguments declared:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--arg1",
        default="dev",
        choices=["real", "test", "dev"],
        help="arg 1"
    )
    parser.add_argument("--arg2", default="0", help="arg 2")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--arg3",
        nargs="+",
        default=["one", "two"],
        choices=["one", "two"],
        help="arg 3",
    )
    parser.add_argument("--arg4", action="store_true", help="arg 4")
    parser.add_argument("--arg5", action="store_true", help="arg 5")
    parser.add_argument("--arg6", action="store_true", help="arg 6")
    parser.add_argument("--arg7", default=None, help="arg 7")

    args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I send an argument that is not defined in these declarations, I get this exception:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: arg8 value
```

Is it possible to indicate `argparse` to accept non declared arguments?

Comment: and what you expect it to do with these?

Comment: to add it as a simple string value, with no validation or additional treatment

Comment: look at `parser.parse_known_args`

Comment: The duplicate suggests `REMAINDER`.  That's still available, but no longer documented.  It has too many rough edge cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ArgumentParser.parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing) parses what it can, and returns a tuple consisting of the `Namespace` object with the results and a list of unrecognized arguments.